# Mobile Background Images Zoomed In

Tags: ios, css, background, responsive-images

I have found several queries along this line, and they either did not have solutions or their solutions didn't work for me.  I have media queries set up, the smallest being max-width (700px), and when I preview the site on my desktop with my browser set to the width of an iPhone, it previews fine.  However, when preview on my actual iPhone, it shows only a very small portion of the photo.  (In both Safari and Chrome.)  I'm unsure about Android devices as I don't have one to test on.

Edit:  Full site at http://www.dragonflyav.com

Here's the CSS:

```css
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    .intro {
        background-image: url("images/backgrounds/fleet-top-770.jpg"); 
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        height: 75vh;
    }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I've tried several variations of the above, including ditching each different property individually, with no luck.  My HTML meta tag is as follows:

```html
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale-1">
```

Comment: Can you provide the html as well (or link to an existing site.) Also you can do a decent test for Android (and many more) using browser tools like Chrome DevTools (if you haven't tried that yet.)

Answer (score 0):

You are overrulling the wrong styling. On the desktop styling you are using:

```
background: url(images/backgrounds/fleet-top-2400.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

and on the responsive you are using:

```
background-image: url("images/backgrounds/fleet-top-770.jpg");
```

This way you will be seeing the desktop image on top of the responsive image. Using just one background property will solve it for you. So I would personally stick to:

```
background-image: url(images/backgrounds/fleet-top-2400.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: I don't think that -image needs to be in there on the last style, but regardless, I changed the media query to the full background shortcut property, and now I have no images showing up on mobile.  I have triple checked file names and everything matches so I don't know if I'm better off than before or worse.

Comment: It works perfectly fine here now? Not sure what your problem is. http://imgur.com/G7JHQza

Comment: Well it started working when I took out the background attachment property of fixed.  I would prefer that it work with that, but apparently it's not possible.